# merge 3 different json array objects into a single json array based on key values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-merge, json-arrayagg

I am trying to merge 3 different json array objects as a single object based on key values in the base json object in JavaScript. I haven't tried anything like this before.
Data looks something like this.

```
var baseObj = [
  { "miId": 1, "val": 2, "smiList": [ { "smiId": '1a', "val": 3 }, { "smiId": '1b', "val": 4 } ] },
  { "miId": 2, "val": 22, "smiList": [ { "smiId": '2a', "val": 33 }, { "smiId": '2b', "val": 43 } ] }
]

var obj1 = [ 
    { "miId": 1, "val": 23, "smiList": [ { "smiId": '1a', "val": 13 }, { "smiId": '1c', "val": 14 } ] },
     { "miId": 4, "val": 24, "smiList": [ { "smiId": '2a', "val": 33 }, { "smiId": '2b', "val": 43 } ] }
]

var obj2 = [ 
    { "miId": 11, "val": 22, "smiList": [ { "smiId": '1a', "val": 53 }, { "smiId": '1c', "val": 14 } ] },
    { "miId": 2, "val": 43, "smiList": [ { "smiId": '2a', "val": 6 }, { "smiId": '2b', "val": 7 } ] }
]
```

My result has to be based on the base json and its key values. its basically like a left of obj1 and obj2 with baseobj array. I need to get all the objects of baseObj along with matched values of obj1 and obj2 based on their keys.

The result has to be:

```
var resultObj = [
  { "miId": 1, "val": 2, "obj1Val" :23, "smiList": [ {"smiId": '1a', "val": 3, "obj1Val": 13}, { "smiId": '1b', "val": 4 } ] },
  { "miId": 2, "val": 22, "obj2Val" :43, "smiList": [ { "smiId": '2a', "val": 33, "obj2Val" :6}, { "smiId": '2b', "val": 43, "obj2Val" :7, } ] }
]
```

can anyone please help me in how to achieve the above result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [JSON](https://json.org/) is only a string. you are dealing with objects inside arrays. what have you tried?

Comment: Hi @Nina Scholz,  I tried to loop through the array but not succeeded in getting the result. Can you please help me if you have any solution for the above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show what you tried and perhaps we can help you with it

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't tried anything like this before.

Split you big problem, into smaller problems then try to solve smaller problem, It would solve itself...

```js
var baseObj = [{ "miId": 1, "val": 2, "smiList": [{ "smiId": '1a', "val": 3 }, { "smiId": '1b', "val": 4 }] }, { "miId": 2, "val": 22, "smiList": [{ "smiId": '2a', "val": 33 }, { "smiId": '2b', "val": 43 }] }]
var obj1 = [{ "miId": 1, "val": 23, "smiList": [{ "smiId": '1a', "val": 13 }, { "smiId": '1c', "val": 14 }] }, { "miId": 4, "val": 24, "smiList": [{ "smiId": '2a', "val": 33 }, { "smiId": '2b', "val": 43 }] }]
var obj2 = [{ "miId": 11, "val": 22, "smiList": [{ "smiId": '1a', "val": 53 }, { "smiId": '1c', "val": 14 }] }, { "miId": 2, "val": 43, "smiList": [{ "smiId": '2a', "val": 6 }, { "smiId": '2b', "val": 7 }] }]
function marge(baseObj, entrys, _id) {
    for (let base of baseObj) {
        for (let [key, obj] of entrys) {
            let item = obj.find(o => o[_id] == base[_id])
            if (!item) continue;
            base[key] = item.val;
            marge(base.smiList || [], [[key, item.smiList]], "smiId")
        }
    }
}
marge(baseObj, [["obj1Val", obj1], ["obj2Val", obj2]], "miId")
console.log("resultObj:", baseObj)
```

Comment: Hi @Nur, Thanks for the answer. Its working as expected in Chrome but giving error in IE11. can you please help.

Comment: Nothing work in Internet Explorer,  You should know which feature is supported by browsers, If you really want to target Internet Explorer , then you should transcompile it in es3 with tool such as Type-Script, Babel etc... there is also many polyfill that you can use to support missing features...