# how to merge 2 object arrays based on keys in JavaScript and retain values of both the arrays when matched

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer-11, array-merge

I am trying to merge 2 object arrays(can be more as well) of same order and fields based on 2 keys. and if the keys matched then maintain the values of array1 and array2. For example:

```
var array1 = [
    { "id": 11, "smid":21, "name":'test1a', "value":0.5 },
    { "id": 12, "smid":22, "name":'test1b', "value":0.6 },
    { "id": 13, "smid":null, "name":'test1b', "value":0.7 }
]
var array2 = [
    { "id": 11, "smid":21, "name":'test2a', "value":1.5 },
    { "id": 22, "smid":32, "name":'test2b', "value":1.6 }
    { "id": 13, "smid":null, "name":'test2c', "value":1.7 },
]
```

The result has to be

```
var resultedArray = [
    { "id": 11, "smid":21, "name":'test1a', "value":0.5, "newValue":[0.5,1.5] },
    { "id": 12, "smid":22, "name":'test1b', "value":0.6, "newValue":[0.6, null] },
    { "id": 13, "smid":null, "name":'test1b', "value":0.7, "newValue":[0.7,1.7] }
]
```

I am able to achieve the above result with the following code.

```
var idFound = false;
for(var ar1Inx = 0; ar1Inx < array1.length;  ar1Inx++){
    idFound = false;
    for(var ar2Inx = 0; ar2Inx < array2.length;  ar2Inx++){
        if(array1[ar1Inx].id == array2[ar2Inx].id && array1[ar1Inx].smid == array2[ar2Inx].smid){
            idFound = true;
            var newArray = [];
            newArray.push(array1[ar1Inx].value);
            newArray.push(array2[ar2Inx].value);
            array1[ar1Inx].["newValue"] = newArray;
        }
    }
    if(!idFound){
        var newArray = [];
        newArray.push(array1[ar1Inx].value);
        newArray.push(null);
        array1[ar1Inx].["newValue"] = newArray;
    }
}
```

But, I want to know, is there a way that I can achieve the expected result in a simple way instead of iterating through each of the arrays which is supported in Internet Explorer 11 with 2 or more arrays. Please advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens with this object `{ "id": 22, "smid":32, "name":'test2b', "value":1.6 }`?

Comment: @NinaScholz, that should be ignored, its like a left join in sql. we get only matched data and ignore other values.

Comment: Wasn't it similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70338956/merge-3-different-json-array-objects-into-a-single-json-array-based-on-key-value)? That you asked before!

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object for reference and an array for collecting.

```js
// function expects arrays as arguments
function leftJoin() {
    function getKey(object) {
        return ['id', 'smid']
            .map(function (k) { return object[k]; })
            .join('|');
    }

    function add(array, index) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            var object = array[i],
                key = getKey(object);

            if (!reference[key]) continue;
            reference[key].value[index] = object.value;
        }
    }
    
    var reference = {},
        result = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments[0].length; i++) {
        var object = arguments[0][i],
            key = getKey(object);

        reference[key] = { id: object.id, smid: object.smid, name: object.name, value: [object.value] };
        for (var j = 1; j < arguments.length; j++) reference[key].value[j] = null;
        result.push(reference[key]);
    }

    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) add(arguments[i], i);
    
    return result;
}

var array1 = [{ id: 11, smid: 21, name: 'test1a', value: 0.5 }, { id: 12, smid: 22, name: 'test1b', value: 0.6 }, { id: 13, smid: null, name: 'test1b', value: 0.7 }],
    array2 = [{ id: 11, smid: 21, name: 'test2a', value: 1.5 }, { id: 22, smid: 32, name: 'test2b', value: 1.6 }, { id: 13, smid: null, name: 'test2c', value: 1.7 }];

console.log(leftJoin(array1, array2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi @Nina Scholz, this is returning unmatched object as well. output should have 3 objects and here also we are iterating through arrays.

Comment: @kavya, please see edit.